# How to use Isolationforest in weka?

Tags: weka

I am trying to use isolationforest in weka ,but I cannot  find a easy example which shows how to use it ,who can help me ?thanks in advance

```
import weka.classifiers.misc.IsolationForest;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IsolationForest isolationForest = new IsolationForest();
        .....................................................
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to study a little bit the implementation for IslationForest.
The following code work loading a CSV file with first column with Class (note: a single class value will produce only (1-anomaly score) if it's binary you will get the anomaly score too. Otherwise it just return an error). Note I skip the second column (that in my case is the uuid that is not needed for anomaly detection)

```
 private static void findOutlier(File in, File out) throws Exception {
    CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
    loader.setSource(new File(in.getAbsolutePath()));

    Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
    // setting class attribute if the data format does not provide this information
    // For example, the XRFF format saves the class attribute information as well
    if (data.classIndex() == -1)
        data.setClassIndex(0);

    String[] options = new String[2];
    options[0] = "-R";                                    // "range"
    options[1] = "2";                                     // first attribute
    Remove remove = new Remove();                         // new instance of filter
    remove.setOptions(options);                           // set options
    remove.setInputFormat(data);                          // inform filter about dataset **AFTER** setting options
    Instances newData = Filter.useFilter(data, remove);   // apply filter

    IsolationForest randomForest = new IsolationForest();
    randomForest.buildClassifier(newData);
   // System.out.println(randomForest);

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(out);
    final Enumeration<Attribute> attributeEnumeration = data.enumerateAttributes();
    for (Attribute e = attributeEnumeration.nextElement(); attributeEnumeration.hasMoreElements(); e = attributeEnumeration.nextElement()) {
        fw.write(e.name());
        fw.write(",");
    }
    fw.write("(1 - anomaly score),anomaly score\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        Instance inst = data.get(i);
        final double[] distributionForInstance = randomForest.distributionForInstance(inst);
        fw.write(inst + ", " + distributionForInstance[0] + "," + (1 - distributionForInstance[0]));
        fw.write(",\n");
    }
    fw.flush();
}
```

The previous function will add at the CSV at last column the anomaly values. Please note I'm using a single class so for getting the corresponding anomaly I do 1 - distributionForInstance[0] otherwise you ca do simply distributionForInstance[1] .

A sample input.csv for getting (1-anomaly score):

```
Class,ignore, feature_0, feature_1, feature_2
A,1,21,31,31
A,2,41,61,81
A,3,61,37,34
```

A sample input.csv for getting (1-anomaly score) and anomaly score:

```
Class,ignore, feature_0, feature_1, feature_2
A,1,21,31,31
B,2,41,61,81
A,3,61,37,34
```